# How To improve a sql query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a view that return to me the customers and `sum` of their payment and its work but it take 8 second and when i remove the computed column part from the query it didn't take any time, and i tried to solve this by creating a non-clustered index on tables but its also 8 second,  so I'm asking about if there is any method to improve the performance,  although i have to use this technique.

my code is

```
SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Total = (
        SELECT Sum(Value)
        FROM TRANSACTION
        WHERE Employee.ID = employee_ID
        )
FROM Employee;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post sizes of the relations?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition to SHOW CREATE TABLES, questions about query performance always require an EXPLAIN

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  I don't think MySQL accepts this syntax for column aliases.

Comment: I'm Sorry its sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a join with group and see if that is faster:

```
 select employee.id, employee.name, sum(value)
 from employee 
 join transaction where transaction.employee_ID = employee.id
 group by employee.id, employee.name
```

Also -  try to avoid to give names that correspond to reserved words - like `TRANSACTION` - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

To hasten up you might want to consider a combined index on `Emlpoyee(id,name)` AND an index on `Transaction.Employee_ID` - both are neede to make the joins and grouping for this query fast.  Check if `transaction.employee_ID` has a `FK_Constraint` to `Employee.ID` - that might help as well.

Comment: yes i'm sure , the data in this table is all transactions so the employee can make more than on transaction , u got it ? and your solution is take the same time .

Comment: HE can not make more then one transaction if your join is correct - at least not if transaction.ID is the unique ID of the ttransaction table.

Comment: This query requires a multicolumn index on employee(id, name)

Comment: Yes I mean That There is a foreign key in this table , and i just named this table transaction here for example to help people to understand the example easy

Comment: @ahmedmohamed  please add the information shown by **describe transaction;**  and same for Employee to your questions. Your simplification does not make sense.

Comment: i made non-clustered index as i mention in the question header and it also doesn't work

Comment: @ahmedmohamed:  just to make sure - you added an index on the column `employee_id` in table `transaction`?

Comment: yes , because i try tuning advisor and it suggest to me to make a non-clustered index on it so i made it , and now when i use a tuning advisor again it not suggest to me anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join in the subselect with the sum

```
select e.id, e.name, t.total 
from employee  e
join (
  select employee_ID, sum(value) as total
  from TRANSACTION
  group by employee_ID
) t on t.employee_ID = e.id
```

Comment: i tried it but it also doesn't work , i started to think that there is no solution for this case

Comment: have you index  on  transaction  employee_id  ??

Comment: Yes I have Index On Employee_Id In table Transaction

Comment: logically i Have a select statement every time so for every row this select statement is run so it have to take a long time and also this table have 50.000 record

Comment: with the  join  the time must be less that then using the  subselect for each rows  .. how is the time difference between the two query?

Comment: try also using a composite index on transaction (employee_ID, value)

Comment: with subselect take 20 second and with join take 19

Comment: strange ...  you are executing the query in an IDE or directly in application

Comment: tuning advisor suggest to me to make it , i made it and no difference and when i run the query now tuning advisor doesn't suggest to me any thing that mean its all good

Comment: i tried the application and the management studio it both take the same time

Comment: what are you referring to with "tuning advisor suggest to me to make it " .?.  i don't understand

Comment: there is a tool in sql server called database engine tuning advisor do you know it ?

Comment: it suggested at the first to make a non-clustered index on transaction table then when i made it , it didn't suggest anything more

Comment: you have done a composite index (employee_ID, value)  or a simple (employee_ID) index ?

Comment: composite index

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
       (SELECT Sum(t.Value)
        FROM TRANSACTION t
        WHERE e.Employee.ID = t.employee_ID
       ) as Total
FROM Employee e;
```

You want an index on `TRANSACTION(employee_ID, Value)`.  That should actually give you optimal performance.

You can write this as a `join` -- but a `left join`:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.NAME, SUM(t.Value) as Total
FROM Employee e JOIN
     TRANSACTION t
     ON e.Employee.ID = t.employee_ID
GROUP BY e.ID, e.NAME;
```

However, the overall `GROUP BY` is usually less efficient than the "sub group by" in MySQL (and often in other databases as well).

Comment: thank you for your time , but i try it and also doesn't make difference

Comment: @ahmedmohamed . . . The index doesn't improve performance?  That is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Try an indexed view on the total

```
CREATE VIEW totalView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    select employee_ID, sum(value) as total
      from TRANSACTION
      group by employee_ID

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_totalView ON totalView
(
    employee_id,total
);
```

Then join to that

```
select employee.id, employee.name, coalesce(t.total,0)
 from employee 
 left outer join totalView t where t.employee_ID = employee.id
```

Adjust the join type according to your need.